# Python client euqivelent of `kubectl rollout restart <deployment>

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm trying to run an automation job in Python that restarts a deployment in Kubernetes cluster. I cannon install `kubectl` on the box due to limited permissions. Does anyone have a suggestion or solution for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

For configuration follow - https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/remote_cluster.py

```
# This is equivalent to `kubectl rollout restart deployment/dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard -n default`


from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
import datetime

def restart_deployment(v1_apps, deployment, namespace):
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    now = str(now.isoformat("T") + "Z")
    body = {
        'spec': {
            'template':{
                'metadata': {
                    'annotations': {
                        'kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt': now
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    try:
        v1_apps.patch_namespaced_deployment(deployment, namespace, body, pretty='true')
    except ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling AppsV1Api->read_namespaced_deployment_status: %s\n" % e)


def main():
    config.load_kube_config(context="minikube")
    # Enter name of deployment and "namespace"
    deployment = "dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard"
    namespace = "default"
    v1_apps = client.AppsV1Api()
    restart_deployment(v1_apps, deployment, namespace)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. I did something similar, adding and modifying an annotation in the deployment.

Answer (score 2):

There is no atomic corresponding operation to the `kubectl rollout restart <deployment>` in the Kubernetes clients. This is an operation that is composed of multiple API calls.

What to do, depends on what you want. To just get a new Pod of the same `Deployment` you can delete a `Pod` alternatively you could add or change an annotation on the `Deployment` to trigger a new rolling-deployment.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to modify an annotation on the existing deployment and the changes are applied successfully but it didn't trigger a POD restart. I'm using the Python client for Kubernetes and `patch_namespaced_deployment` API call. Although this has a `force` option, it returned me an error `Forbidden: may not be specified for non-apply patch` when I set its value to `True`. What am I doing wrong here? 
I couldn't find any resources related to this in Google search.

Comment: You probably need to change the annotation within the `template:`-part of the `Deployment` to trigger new Pods.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps a lot.